# How do you programmatically find a true URL in C# instead of a forwarding link?

Tags: c#, url

Another way to ask this question is this: How do you programmatically expand a TinyURL link to its true location?

What I want to do is to find a way to programmatically take the link:

```
http://www.baidu.com/link?url=mW91GJqjJ4zBBpC8yDF8xDhiqDSn1JZjFWsHhEoSNd85PkV8Xil7qccoOX3rynaE
```

(the first link in a search for Jessica Alba using baidu.com) and have it return the actual link:

```
http://baike.baidu.com/view/270790.htm
```

That is just one example.  What I want to do is not specific to Jessica but for using Baidu.com as part of my group of search engines in my meta search engine project.

Maybe there is a way of using the `WebBrowser` class but I did not see a member that was the URL.

Maybe there is a way of using `WebRequest` and `WebResponse`.

Answer (score 2):

Make a request to tinied URL, and parse out the HTTP response `Location` header.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, it's nice and easy!

```
var WReq = WebRequest.Create("http://www.baidu.com/link?url=mW91GJqjJ4zBBpC8yDF8xDhiqDSn1JZjFWsHhEoSNd85PkV8Xil7qccoOX3rynaE");
WReq.Method = "HEAD";   // Only download the headers, not the page content
var ActualURL = WReq.GetResponse().ResponseUri.ToString();
MessageBox.Show(ActualURL);
```

[image]

Comment: But this solution reads also reads the actual page `http://baike.baidu.com/view/270790.htm` unnecessarily.

Comment: So take out the `MessageBox`... it's there only to demonstrate easily that it works.

Comment: Danny it is not related with `MessageBox`. Use Fiddler and see the result.

Comment: @L.B Ah, you mean that it retrieves the page content? Your own answer has the exact same call to `GetResponse()`.

Comment: Danny no, I used `AllowAutoRedirect=false`. Use a proxy like Fiddler and compare the results.

Comment: @L.B The best way to do this is to set `WReq.Method = "HEAD"` - this only downloads the headers, not the page content. Fiddler then shows a download size of 0, instead of 143kb. Thanks for the idea, I've edited my answer! :)

Comment: Although it doesn't download the contents of the pages now, it still makes two page requests where the first request is enough. Also, `HEAD` is not supported by all web servers.

Comment: The 2nd request is required. What if URL2 redirects to another URL? I.e. URL1 > URL2 > URL3.

Answer (score 1):

```
string url = "http://www.baidu.com/link?url=mW91GJqjJ4zBBpC8yDF8xDhiqDSn1JZjFWsHhEoSNd85PkV8Xil7qccoOX3rynaE";
var req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false; //<--!!!!
var resp = req.GetResponse();
var realUrl = resp.Headers["Location"]; //http://baike.baidu.com/view/270790.htm
```

PS: The key point here is the **`req.AllowAutoRedirect = false`**

Comment: This would not work if there is more than 1 redirect. It would go to URL1 -> Try to redirect to URL2 -> Quit, returning URL2. What if URL2 redirects to URL3? The correct solution is `req.Method = "HEAD"`, per my answer.